# How do we set the background image to a div in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i have a images folder which has 2 images. Please refer the following code
App.js code

```
import "./styles.css";
import nf_logo from "./images/netflix_logo.png";
import nf_bg from "./images/netflix_bg.jpg";

const divStyle = {
  backgroundImage: `url(${nf_logo})`
};
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div style={divStyle}></div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: What happens if you just inline the full path in the divStyle: `backgroundImage: url(./images/netflix_logo.png)` ?

Comment: Still not working... You can fork the sandbox here
https://codesandbox.io/s/netflixclone-zt2xn

Comment: why not specifying it in css file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the `width` and `height` of the div, or at least set those properties high and wide enough so you can see the image.

```js
function Example() {

  const divStyle = {
    width: '150px',
    height: '150px',
    backgroundImage: `url(https://dummyimage.com/150x150/000/fff)`
  };

  return (
    <div style={divStyle} />
  );
};

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <Example />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

If your `div` is larger than your div just set the `backgroundRepeat` property to `no-repeat'.

```js
function Example() {

  const divStyle = {
    width: '250px',
    height: '250px',
    backgroundImage: `url(https://dummyimage.com/150x150/000/fff)`,
    backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat'
  };

  return (
    <div style={divStyle} />
  );
};

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <Example />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the head-up @PeterB

Answer (score 0):

I usually import the image at the top of my component from the file system and then assign it to the component that needs it as background:

```
    import React from 'react';
    import backgroundImage from './some/local/place.png'

    export const Header = () => (
        <container style={{ backgroundImage: `linear-gradient(176.27deg, rgba(7, 7, 7, 0.35) 3.06%, #070707 74.05%), url( ${ backgroundImage } )` }}>
            {otherComponentsAndStuff}
        </container>
);
```